# How to setup the Cloudflare and Google Cloud Storage to benefit from discounted CDN Interconnect link

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloudflare

I am now using Google Cloud Storage to store the static files and serving through Cloudflare as CDN.

I just learned that there is a partnership between Cloudflare and Google Cloud Platform that can heavily reduce the bandwidth cost by 75% as mentioned in this link https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002374208-How-do-I-get-Google-CDN-Interconnect-discount-using-Cloudflare-

Unfortunately, *there is no any document written about how to configure this properly at all*.

Anyway I have tried every single possible way to connect those two services together by myself, such as:

- Configure a CNAME of subdomain pointing to `c.storage.googleapis.com`
- Configure a CNAME of subdomain pointing to `<bucket_name>.storage.googleapis.com`
- Create a Premium-tier load balancer to deliver files from a specific IP reserved and configure an A record pointing to that IP

My files could be served perfectly with every single setup shown above but I still have no luck getting the cost reducing with `Network Egress via Carrier Peering Network - Americas Based` described in the attached link above. Only service appeared in my usage billing is `Network Internet Egress from Americas to Americas` which is much more expensive (3 times more expensive).

Please note that my bucket is in USA (Multi-Regional) and the majority of traffic are also from USA.

If anyone here that appear to has some experience on how to configure it to gain the benefit from Cloudflare-GCP CDN Interconnect, it would be great and really be appreciate if you can share your configuration right now.

Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: 1) The Google CDN interconnect is "Intra-region". This means only traffic within the same region is eligible. That would not include all the US. Only approved locations are part of the agreement. 2) Once you have completed #1 contact Google Billing for billing/pricing issues. We cannot help you on Stackoverflow with partnership agreements or billing questions.

Comment: 3) You have to work with CloudFlare to set up the deployment. This is not something you configure. CloudFlare does this for you. Google then whitelists approved IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks! I just contacted Cloudflare and the support team said that there is nothing they could do on CF side. Contacting Google support right now about the issue. Hope to here from them soon. =)